# tkinter key-binding won't work

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am trying to make a program which will react to key-presses and play certain mp3 files. Here's a piece of the code:

```
from pygame import mixer 
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk() 
def playBDT():
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load("Ba Dum Tss!.mp3")
    mixer.music.play()  

button2 = Button(root, command = playBDT)
button2.bind("<KeyPress-X>", playBDT)
button2.grid(row=0,column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Now when i run this i get a frame with a button. When i click the button the sound plays normally. However, when i press the X key nothing happens. How can i fix it? Also if i were to play a game with this program running in the background, will the sounds play when i press the corresponding keys?

Comment: `bind` to `root`. btw: `bind` send `event` to function so use `playBDT(event=None)` to  use this function with `bind` and `command`.

Comment: operation system doesn't send key events to program running in background. Maybe you need Autohotkey (Window) or Autokey (Linux) to grab pressed key.

Comment: Key bindings are case sensitive, so you might actually want `"<Key-x>"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but i don't know if this works for you.

```py
button2 = Button(root, command = playBDT)
button2.focus_force()
button2.bind("<KeyPress-X>", playBDT)
button2.grid(row=0,column=0)
```